# Flash standalone player resize event stops firing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resize, event-listener

this is a weird one.

In our Flash project, we add a listener for stage resize events so we can do some dynamic resizing. At the moment we're not running it in a browser, just testing it in the standalone Flash player, and it has been working fine but recently, for some reason the events are no longer being triggered. What's odd is that it appears to be something code-related because when I switch over to a different chunk of code, the events still trigger - but I can't see any reason for it. The listener is still on the stage and its willTrigger is still true.

I know this is all a bit vague, but any suggestions would be valuable!

Again, just to be very clear, I'm *not* talking about running it in a browser, so this isn't anything to do with setting the resize settings in HTML.

Thanks

Comment: How does the code look like? How does the other code it is still working with look like?

Comment: "I think it's code related". Yeah probably. Was there a question here somewhere? Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it were an AIR app i would suggest adding your event listener to NativeApplication.nativeApplication instead of the stage, a long time ago i had a similar intermittent problem and that was the fix. However i think thats only available for AIR. You can try to change your publiah settings to an AIR app just to see if it works. If it still doesnt work id have to assume its something code related on your part. willTrigger sounds suspicious :)